# Shortest path that avoids a ball

Tags: geometry, reference-request, euclidean-geometry, spheres, geodesic

Given an open ball $B=B(\xi,r) \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, and two points $x,y \notin B$, **how long** (by Euclidean metric) is the shortest path from $x$ to $y$ that does not intersect $B$?

I am in a context where a **reference** is much more useful than a proof.

By considering a plane which includes $x$, $y$ and $\xi$, the problem reduces to a problem of avoiding a circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I guess this can be found as an exercise in an elementary geometry book, but that literature is very unfamiliar to me.

Comment: I would guess you draw the straight line between $x$ and $y$; if this does not cut $B$ you have your solution.  If it does then take the plane which contains this line and the centre of $B$, and so also a great circle of $B$.  Now draw the tangents of this circle from $x$ and $y$: the shortest path will be along these tangents to $B$ and along the great-circle arc joining the tangency points (you may have a couple of choices to make between tangents or arcs; if so then choose the shorter tangents and then the shorter arcs) options)

Comment: @Henry Yes, I know. I'm looking for a reference, rather than a proof.